# Ayuda para quitar la barra de desplazamiento de la consola

Tags: c++.net

[image: Imagen pantallazo]

El objetivo es que no se muestren las barras de desplazamiento

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{

    int x=10;
    int y=5;

    Console::SetWindowSize(70,40);
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Magenta;cout<<"          __    __  _______   __    __                    ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Magenta;cout<<"         /  |  /  |/       \ /  \  /  |                   ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Magenta;cout<<"         $$ |  $$ |$$$$$$$  |$$  \  $$ |                   ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Magenta;cout<<"         $$ |  $$ |$$ |__$$ |$$$  \ $$ |                   ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Magenta;cout<<"         $$ |  $$ |$$    $$/ $$$$  $$ |                   ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Magenta;cout<<"         $$ |  $$ |$$$$$$$/  $$ $$ $$ |                   ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Magenta;cout<<"         $$ \__ $$ |$$ |      $$ |$$$$ |                   ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Magenta;cout<<"         $$    $$/ $$ |      $$ | $$$ |                   ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Magenta;cout<<"          $$$$$$/  $$/       $$/   $$/                    ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Magenta;cout<<endl;
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Magenta;cout<<endl;
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Magenta;cout<<" _______   ______  __     __  ________  _______  ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Magenta;cout<<"/       \ /      |/  |   /  |/        |/       \ ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Magenta;cout<<"$$$$$$$  |$$$$$$/ $$ |   $$ |$$$$$$$$/ $$$$$$$  |";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Magenta;cout<<"$$ |__$$ |  $$ |  $$ |   $$ |$$ |__    $$ |__$$ |";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Magenta;cout<<"$$    $$<   $$ |   $$  \ /$$/ $$    |   $$    $$< ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Magenta;cout<<"$$$$$$$  |  $$ |   $$  /$$/  $$$$$/    $$$$$$$  |";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Magenta;cout<<"$$ |  $$ | _$$ |_   $$ $$/   $$ |_____ $$ |  $$ |";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Magenta;cout<<"$$ |  $$ |/ $$   |   $$$/    $$       |$$ |  $$ |";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Magenta;cout<<"$$/   $$/ $$$$$$/     $/     $$$$$$$$/ $$/   $$/ ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Magenta;cout<<endl;


    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Cyan;cout<<"\tFUNDAMENTOS DE ALGORITMOS - > 2017-01"<<endl;
    Console::SetCursorPosition(20,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::DarkCyan;cout<<"01000011 00100000 00100000"<<endl;
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);cout<<endl;
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);cout<<endl;
    Console::SetCursorPosition(30,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Yellow;cout<<"Jugador: "<<char(4)<<endl;
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);cout<<endl;
    Console::SetCursorPosition(30,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::White;cout<<"Enemigo: "<<char(193)<<endl;
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);cout<<endl;
    Console::SetCursorPosition(30,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Cyan;cout<<"Nave: "<<char(34)<<endl;
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);cout<<endl;
    Console::SetCursorPosition(30,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Red;cout<<"Bonus: "<<char(169)<<endl;
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);cout<<endl;
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);cout<<endl;
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);cout<<endl;
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y++);Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Green;cout<<"Presione <ESCAPE> para continuar o <S> para salir"<<endl;


    _getch();                                
    return 0;
}
```

<sub>Nota: Lograr el objetivo ayudaría en mi calificación a comparación de los demás</sub>

Comment: Que es lo que estas intentando, aclara tu pregunta o seguramente sera cerrada como "no esta claro lo que se pregunta" o como "demasiado amplia"

Comment: Que tiene esto que ver con vb.net?

Comment: Visual Basic Std

Comment: *PaperBirdMaster* ha sido golpeado por *Muro de texto*. ¡Es muy efectivo!. *PaperBirdMaster* Muere.

Comment: @GiovanniSobrinoPerez Por favor, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/74956/edit) tu pregunta y aclara exactamente lo que quieres hacer. **Creo** que lo que pretendes es que no se muestren las barras de desplazamiento, ¿ cierto ?

Comment: Claro quiero saber si es que se puede hacer ese detalle de las barras de desplazamiento pienso que estan demas y ayudarian en mi calificacion a comparacion de los demas

Comment: Giovanni: lo que realmente te ayudaría es buscar un poco antes de preguntar. Lee por favor con detenimiento [ask] y pasa por el [tour], pues las preguntas que estás formulando necesitan mejora.

Answer (score 3):

Basándome en esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471520/how-to-remove-scrollbars-in-console-windows-c) en el sitio en Ingles. Que hace referencia mismamente a este [foro](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/43203-disable-console-scrollbar.html). El ejemplo minimo que se debe hacer para retirar las barras de desplazamiento es el siguiente:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HANDLE hOut;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO SBInfo;
    COORD NewSBSize;
    int Status;

    hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hOut, &SBInfo);
    NewSBSize.X = SBInfo.dwSize.X - 2;
    NewSBSize.Y = SBInfo.dwSize.Y;

    Status = SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hOut, NewSBSize);
    if (Status == 0)
    {
        Status = GetLastError();
        cout << "SetConsoleScreenBufferSize() failed! Reason : " << Status << endl;
        exit(Status);
    }

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hOut, &SBInfo);

    cout << "Screen Buffer Size : ";
    cout << SBInfo.dwSize.X << " x ";
    cout << SBInfo.dwSize.Y << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

<sub>He respondido basándome directamente en la respuesta en ingles.</sub>

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero me parece que trasladamos un mensaje malo aquí: alguien quiere mejorar la nota en la asignatura, no busca ni nada y simplemente pregunta en este sitio sin mostrar ningún tipo de esfuerzo. Tú le respondes con una respuesta que consiste en haber buscado :) Ante todo, gracias por el esfuerzo, pero no sé si queremos pregutnas de este tipo y ayudarlos _tanto_ a cambio de nada puede hacer que proliferen.

Comment: @fedorqui totalmente cierto, el OP de la pregunta no valorara nada el esfuerzo que conlleva responder correctamente una pregunta (y mas aun cuando yo mismo he editado su pregunta 3 veces para que vaya quedando mas clara). Pero aunque el OP no muestre interés, en el futuro puede que alguien realmente lo necesite, y no tendrá la necesidad de preguntar, ya que hay una pregunta correctamente editada (mas o menos) y una respuesta aparentemente valida, puede que el OP no muestre interés por esto, pero la pregunta/respuesta pueden ser interesantes para cualquier otra persona.

Comment: Es el eterno debate... Yo creo que es probablemente mejor eliminar la pregunta y preparar una tú mismo con pregunta->respuesta para cubrir todos los aspectos. Cuanto mejor reputación tenga una pregunta, más fácil será de encontrar (el SEO le mejora) y así como lo planteó el OP raramente tendrá. Por el contrario, una cosa bien aseadita seguro que despierta más simpatía. Pero vaya, este es un tema recurrente en Meta al que cuesta encontrarle la solución.

Comment: @fedorqui supongo que lo mejor sería preparar una pregunta bien formulada con una respuesta y una explicación mas concisa y precisa, explicando lo que hace el codigo (no solo pegandolo), desgraciadamente seria incapaz de hacerlo ya que he respondido basandome en otra pregunta  y mi conocimiento sobre C++ es bastante bajo. En cualquier caso si la pregunta es cerrada tampoco lo veria mal.

Comment: Entiendo. Te honra la sinceridad :) Yo mismo hice alguna vez esto en [so] pero a la larga empecé a pensar que tiende a agrandar el problema, pues al final nos encontramos con 1) uno que pregunta sin buscar y 2) uno que responde sin saber demasiado, por lo que acabamos con una pregunta mala y una respuesta parcheada. A ver qué opina la comunidad.

Comment: @fedorqui Hombre para estan las ediciones, pero como has dicho lo mejor sera ver que opina la comunidad

Answer (score 0):

Haga clic con el botón derecho del ratón en la barra de título, seleccione propiedades y, en la pestaña de diseño, asegúrese de que la altura de la ventana coincida con la altura del búfer de la pantalla.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No es mala idea, aunque no puedes pedirle al usuario que haga eso porque nada te garantiza que te vaya a hacer caso.